# SQL: Get real time data from different database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert data from database1 into database2 when something changes. Like a trigger but the thing is I am not allowed to create a trigger in database1.

I basically need to insert certain data into a table from a database into another database as they happen.

Any suggestions would be great!
Thanx

Comment: What about database replication? And what's your DBMS?

Comment: SQL Server 2012, Cool i'll try that but I was thinking about a simpler solution. And it is only specific columns not a copy of the whole table

Answer (score 0):

What about the merge operator ?

Merge operator will commit changes into the target table from the source table when something change.

As you cannot use trigger this cannot be a real time process but with a process scheduler like SQL Agent, you can run it each 10 seconds depending on your table size.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

You can do it when your source come from multiple table by using CTE like that :

```
With TableSources As
(
    Select id,Column1, Column2 from table1
    UNION 
    Select id,Colum1,Column2 from table2
)
MERGE INTO TargetTable
USING TableSources ON TargetTable.id=TableSources.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target
Insert(Column1,Column2) Values(Column1,Column2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source
Delete
WHEN MATCHED
Update Set Column1=TableSources.Column1, Column2=TableSources.Column2
;
```

Comment: I take different columns from different tables and put them together in this database, it is not possible with merge is it? at the moment I am trying a stored proc with an insert or update query that run with the agent but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a program to do that, there are many ways instead but I think this is the straightforward and easy one.
For example if you work with SQL server you can create C# code that connect to the two databases and check for data in the first one then send it to the second.

For example:
you can create a trigger for the first DB tables you want to check them, then you can create a web service that check if the trigger fire, it will get the data from first database and send it to the second, this will be better to enhance and you can change the code to do whatever you want without making any changes from the database side

Comment: That is a good idea, unfortunately I am crazy bad with coding. SQL is my comfort zone :)

Answer (score 0):

[MS SQL Server Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.110).aspx)

I think suitable for you is [Transactional Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176(v=sql.110).aspx)
Transactional replication is asynchronous but close to real time